# Fetching user_birthday from Facebook with MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, oauth

Hello stack overflow friends, need some help here.  I am trying to write a basic .NET application for fun which lets users log in through Facebook and catpures their email and birthday.

in Startup.auth.cs I use:

```
var facebookAuthenticationOptions = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AppId = "foo",
            AppSecret = "bar",
        };
        facebookAuthenticationOptions.Scope.Add("email");
        facebookAuthenticationOptions.Scope.Add("user_birthday");
        facebookAuthenticationOptions.SignInAsAuthenticationType = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AppBuilderSecurityExtensions.GetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(app);
        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookAuthenticationOptions);
```

I then in my Controller use:

```
    if (user != null)
    {
        await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);

        //Get external user data...
        var externalIdentity = await HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication
               .GetExternalIdentityAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        var email = externalIdentity.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
        var birthday = externalIdentity.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.DateOfBirth);

        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }
```

The email is there but the birthday is null.  What is going on?  How can I capture birthday and other user events?

Comment: Did you gave the user the birthday permission? You can check it here: https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications

Comment: Yes the user is prompted to give the app permission when you log in.  It says "This app accesses your birthday" and you authorize it.  Just the var birthday is not filled in.

Comment: You sure the `ClaimTypes.DateOfBirth` is the right way to fetch the birthday? Log the complete json object

Comment: How to I capture the complete JSON object from externalIdentity.  I'm kind of a rookie at this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `externalIdentity.FindFirstValue("user_birthday");`. That is the claim that your asking for.